# Отличие this от scope в angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В angular к данным в контроллере можно обращаться через ключевое слово $scope или дать алиас контроллеру и тогда обращаться через $this. В чем разница ?

Comment: можно пример обращения через `$this`? где происходит это обращение?

Answer (score 1):

При использовании синтаксиса "controller as" в $scope создается объект в котором и хранятся все методы контроллера, это дает возможность использовать эти методы в любом из дочерних $scope, например во вложенном контроллере:

```js
var ControllerOne = function($scope) {
  var _this = this;
  _this.$scope = $scope;
  _this.$scope.name = 'Vladimir';
};

ControllerOne.prototype = {
  alert: function() {
    var _this = this;
    alert('Hello ' + _this.$scope.name);
  }
};


var ControllerTwo = function($scope) {
  var _this = this;
  _this.$scope = $scope;

};

angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('controllerOne', ['$scope', ControllerOne])
  .controller('controllerTwo', ['$scope', ControllerTwo]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="controllerOne as ctrl">
  <div ng-controller="controllerTwo as parentCtrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.alert()">Alert</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: скорее не _создается объект в котором и хранятся все методы контроллера_, а сохраняется созданный экземпляр контроллера

Comment: Ну и в твоем примере нет обращения через _$this_

Comment: а в чем смысл сохранять _this_ внутри функции alert? он же прям там и используется сразу, не говоря уже о том, что нет смысла зацикливать объекты, сохраняя `$scope` в котором хранится ссылка на контроллер, в этот контроллер. Даже больше того, `$scope` в данном случае вообще не нужен

Comment: Строка var  _this = this; Дает нам доступ к сохраненному _this в функции контроллера, так как вешаем метод на прототип, нам не доступна переменная _this через замыкание.

Comment: Ничего не понял, где тут замыкания, но если тут убрать это присвоение - ничего не поменяется, как впрочем ничего не поменяется если еще и $scope убрать

Comment: Если Вы так уверенны, попробуйте, Жду ваш код. Только учтите что при использовании "controller as" функция контроллера используется в казачестве конструктора.

Comment: [пример, что я имел ввиду](http://plnkr.co/edit/Idt5mUgnSAON0tShu0Wp?p=preview)

Comment: В вашем примере переменная `name` не находится в `$scope`, следственно она не может использоваться в  view. Повторюсь, что при использовании controller as функция используется в качестве конструктора, соответственно нам нужно сохранить все переданные  в неё зависимости.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44033/discussion-between-grundy-and-d-nazarenko).